# How can I control the name of a generic WCF Message Contract

Tags: .net, wcf

I'm generating a WCF service using the message contract model.

I have created a generic request message contract like so:

```
[MessageContract]
public Request<T>
{
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public T Details { get; set; }
}
```

I'm used to using `[DataContract(Name="Contract{0}")]` to produce readable names for generic data contracts, but this approach does not seem to work for me using message contracts.

Is there a way to achieve the same behaviour using the message contract model?

Answer (score 4):

It seems like a lot of work for what you want to accomplish, but I believe you can create a MessageInspector which will allow you to interact directly with the XML.

Client message inspectors implement the `IClientMessageInspector` interface and service message inspectors implement the `IDispatchMessageInspector` interface.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047.aspx

Any service (dispatcher) message inspector must implement the two `IDispatchMessageInspector` methods `AfterReceiveRequest` and `BeforeSendReply`.

The link goes into much more detail, but once you have these implemented, you should be able to add the inspector to your web.config and you should be all set.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the question. Given there is a generic MessageContract e.g. `Request<T>`, how does one have a *clean* name generated in the WSDL for inputs that are closed generic types of `Request<T>` e.g. `Request<ServiceInput>`. The OP would like to generate a name such as `RequestOfServiceInput` in the WSDL for the former generic type, but it seems that naming generic types for MessageContracts do not work the same as DataContracts as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731045.aspx#sectionSection4

Comment: You may be correct @RussCam. In that case, he would need to use `IWsdlExportExtension` to customize/extend the WSDL. You can find an example of that here:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/skaufman/archive/2009/05/29/exposing-custom-wcf-headers-through-wcf-behaviors.aspx

Answer (score 2):

There's a `WrapperName` and `WrapperNamespace` property on the `MessageContract` attribute that I think does the same thing. E.g.,

```
[MessageContract(WrapperName = "FooMessage", IsWrapped = true)]
public class Request<T>
{ ... }
```

Note the addition of the `IsWrapped` property to indicate that the message should be serialized into the wrapper element.

Comment: I tried this using WrapperName = "WrapperFor{0}", but this resolved to a pretty nasty name in the WSDL (the Unicode equivalent of {0}) and did not perform the translation I had expected.

Comment: In addition, this seems to throw an exception when `T` also happens to be a generic type and the `DataContract Name` property uses placeholders e.g. `GenericOf{0}`. I'd be interested to know if Generic MessageContracts and DataContracts can be used together with overridden generic names so I've put a bounty on this question