# WCF exposing generic type 'T'

Tags: wcf

I write a WCF service for Insert and delete operation here we used generic method but it gives following error
"System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException: Type 'T' cannot be exported as a schema type because it is an open generic type. You can only export a generic type if all its generic parameter types are actual types."

here "EntityBase2" is base class for all entities

```
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(EntityBase2))]
public interface IBackupUtility
{
    [OperationContract]
    void Delete<T>(T entity) where T : EntityBase2;

    [OperationContract]
    void InsertORUpdate<T>(T entity) where T : EntityBase2;        
}
```

Question is how i can expose generic type 'T'?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WCF. Service generic methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906694/wcf-service-generic-methods)

Answer (score 7):

I think it is imposible, how could it generate the wsdl that way?

You have two options:

- You could send the type as a parameter.
- If you want to expose crud operations for entities I would recommend to use a code generator, maybe a T4 template for EF.

Answer (score 7):

This post is old indeed, but maybe someone find this solution useful:
[WCF and Generics](http://jeffbarnes.net/blog/post/2007/05/10/WCF-Serialization-and-Generics.aspx)

Comment: Perfect. Helped significantly!

Comment: Helpful Hint in that article on how to remove the Hash! [DataContract(Name = "MyGenericObjectUsing{0}"]
public class MyGenericObject<T>

Answer (score 1):

1. Answer to this question is both Yes and No. Yes for server prospective and No for client prospective.
2. We can create a generic Data Contract on server but while using that in any operation contract we have to specify a data type of the generic.
3. And at client end that data contract will be exposed only as a strongly data type not generic.

   ```
   [DataContract]
   public class MyGenericObject<T>
   {
      private T _id;

      [DataMember]
      public T ID
      {
         get { return _id; }
         set { _id = value; }
      }
   }

   [OperationContract]
   MyGenericObject<int> GetGenericObject();
   ```

This is what we have in Server we can see while using generic data contract we have to specify the type otherwise it’ll give compile time error.

**On client what we get from WSDL is a follow:**

```
[DataContract]
public class MyGenericObjectOfint
```

We can see here what we get from WSDL is not a generic data contract WSDL proxy generate a class with a new name using some convention.

Convention used is

*Generic Class Name + "Of" + Type Parameter Name + Hash*

Hash is not always generated, it’ll be generated only when there is a chance of name collision.

Comment: @Vikas...do you know if there's a way I can override that convention?

Comment: @JohnnyWu ... Please check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961654/how-can-i-control-the-name-of-a-generic-wcf-message-contract