# GUID in vb script (WCF service moniker)

Tags: wcf, vbscript

I have a problem with a webservice I'm calling from vbscript. The service has a method which I need to call, which has a Guid as one of the parameters. I don't know how to pass along the guid to the webservice. Tried it like this:

```
proxy.SiteExists "{A523D7D2-692A-4464-9B0F-FED023641F03}", "/site"
```

the proxy object (WCF service moniker) is created without any problems and I can call a test ping ok. The above causes the following error message:

```
"Type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey, TValue]' 
cannot be exported as a schema type because it is an open generic type. 
You can only export a generic type if all generic parameter types are 
actual types."
```

Maybe there's something wrong with the way I'm passing in the parameters, or passing a Guid as a string isn't correct?

Comment: The same error raises in the following SO questions, maybe there is an answer for you there? [Click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732411/wcf-exposing-generic-type-t) and [click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906694/wcf-service-generic-methods).

Comment: Nope, those are about generation of the wsdl server side. My question is strictly client side, the wsdl already exists and is properly exposing guid as the parameter type for that particular method.

Comment: Okay, this is clearly not my field of expertise. I do have experience with GUIDs though and sometimes run into issues in formatting GUIDs. Have you tried supplying the GUID without brackets? Like: `A523D7D2-692A-4464-9B0F-FED023641F03`?

Comment: Sorry, it seems you did have a point referring to the other topics. I thought it was related with the GUIDs, but it's not. It was the use of a Hashtable in one of the other methods which apparantly isn't compatible when used like this. I replaced it with two seperate arrays and now it works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: Great to hear and glad I could help! Can you add your answer as an answer to your question? The next fellow could learn from this question and the solution you found.