# Create Polymorphic method on partial class to send generic type on c#

Tags: c#, wcf, polymorphism

I want to implement a generic List procedure to various partial C# classes. I will use this generic method to fill comboboxes for filtering data.

So far i have try this:

**Interface**

First I create a generic interface and a custom class

```
public class Enumerador
{
    public int ID{ get; set; }
    public string Description{ get; set; }
}

interface IEnumerador
{
    IEnumerable<Enumerador> Enumerar();
}
```

Then on every class i want this behavior I implement this interface like this:

```
 public IEnumerable<Enumerador> Enumerar()
    {
        using (var context = new OhmioEntities())
        {
            Clientes _allClients = new Clientes();
            _allClients.RazonFantasia = "Any Client";
            _allClients.ID_Cliente = -1;
            var query = context.Clientes;
            var _clients = query.Where(f => f.Activo == true).OrderBy(o => RazonFantasia).ToList();
            _clients.Insert(0, _allClients);

            var p = from cli in _clients
                    select new Enumerador { ID = cli.ID_Cliente, Description = cli.RazonFantasia };
            return p.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Now i get a generic list filled and returned. Now my problem is that i need to send this to client over WCF, and i want a generic (polymorphic?) method to do that.
So far i resolve it like this:

**Method A**

```
public IEnumerable<Enumerador> GetClients()
    {
        Clientes _cli = new Clientes();
        return _cli.Enumerar();            
    }
```

**Method B**

```
public IEnumerable<Enumerador> GetVendors()
    {
        Vendors _vnd = new Vendors();
        return _vnd.Enumerar();            
    }
```

**So my questions are**

*Is there a polymorphic generic way to write Method A and Method B on a single procedure (Because they respond with same generic type)?

*Will this be compatible with WCF service? Thanks for everything!

**UPDATE**

Ok. I half way done. Now it almos work. I've modified my method like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Enumerador> GetEnumerador<T>() where T : IEnumerador, new()
    {
        T _obj = new T();
        return _obj.Enumerar();  
    }
```

If i call it from within the class work great. But if a call it from WCF Cliente i get:

> The non generic Method
>   'Ohmio.Client.OhmioService.OhmioServiceClient.GetEnumerador()' cannot
>   be used with types arguments

Any Idea?

**UPDATE 2**

This is my service contract:

```
public interface IOhmioService
{        
    [OperationContract]
    IEnumerable<Enumerador> GetEnumerador<T>() where T : IEnumerador, new();        
}
```

This is my class implementation:

```
public class OhmioService : IOhmioService
{
    public IEnumerable<Enumerador> GetEnumerador<T>() where T : IEnumerador, new()
    {
        T _obj = new T();
        return _obj.Enumerar();  
    }
}
```

And call it from client like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Enumerador> Clients { get; set; } 
Clients = this.serviceClient.GetEnumerador<Clientes>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Enumerador> GetClients<T>() where T : IEnumerador, new()
{
    T _cli = new T();
    return _cli.Enumerar();            
}
```

It forces `T` to be `IEnumerador` and have a parameterless constructor.

Call it like this:

```
IEnumerable<Enumerador> c = GetClients<Clientes>();
```

And

```
IEnumerable<Enumerador> v = GetClients<Vendors>();
```

Comment: That seems to be exactly what i need. I didn't now how to have a parameterless constructor. I'll try this! Can you give a little more details about what "where T : IEnumerador, new()" ecactly means? Thanks!

Comment: I enforces that T derives the interfaces, classes or pseudo-classes (`new()`) you specify.

Comment: I edited the way you suggest, but the problem persist. Could it be because client cannot see interface IEnumerador?

Comment: @ericpap: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732411/wcf-exposing-generic-type-t