# Error when calling Polymorphic method on WCF Client

Tags: c#, wcf

This error comes as result of [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23366706/create-polymorphic-method-on-partial-class-to-send-generic-type-on-c-sharp/23366791) previous question. I'm trying to call a polymorphic method from WCF client. This is my contract:

```
public interface IOhmioService
{        
  [OperationContract]
  IEnumerable<Enumerador> GetEnumerador<T>() where T : IEnumerador, new();        
}
```

This is my class implementation:

```
public class OhmioService : IOhmioService
{
  public IEnumerable<Enumerador> GetEnumerador<T>() where T : IEnumerador, new()
  {
      T _obj = new T();
      return _obj.Enumerar();  
  }
}
```

And call it from client like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Enumerador> Clients { get; set; } 
Clients = this.serviceClient.GetEnumerador<Clientes>();
```

If i call this method from within the class everything works fine. But if i call it from WCF client a get this error:

> The non generic Method 'Ohmio.Client.OhmioService.OhmioServiceClient.GetEnumerador()' 
>   cannot be used with types arguments

What i'm i doing wrong? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Ok. I try suggested solution, and get this Horrible error:

> Type 'System.RuntimeType' wasn't spected with the contract name RuntimeType:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System'. Trye to use DataContractResolver or add the unknown types staticaly to the list of known types (for instance, using the attribute KnownTypeAttribute or adding them to the list of known types to pass to DataContractSerializer)

Maybe using generic types over wcf is not such a good idea after all. I was trying to reduce repetitive code on the WCF service.

Comment: How is this polymorphic? It is not virtual.

Comment: Sorry @The Mouth of a Cow, maybe i'm a little confuse here. I asume this is Polymorphic because it calls a generic method on multiple objects depending on desire type. Still have some idea of why i get this error?

Comment: Polymorphism is synonymous with virtual methods: it means deciding which method to call at runtime based on the objects real type, not its compile time. What you have above is an entirely compile time construct. I've proposed a solution for you below.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have generic `OperationContract` methods in a WCF `ServiceContract`. See here for further details: [WCF. Service generic methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906694/wcf-service-generic-methods)

You need to pass the type as a method parameter:

```
public interface IOhmioService
{        
  [OperationContract]
  IEnumerable<Enumerador> GetEnumerador(string typeName);       
}

public class OhmioService : IOhmioService
{
  public IEnumerable<Enumerador> GetEnumerador(string typeName)
  {
      var type = Type.GetType(typeName);
      var _obj = (IEnumerador)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
      return _obj.Enumerar();  
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

See update above; pass the fully qualified name of the type. That won't cause a serialization issue.

Comment: Ok I try this, but get an horrorif error that i'll translate as update on original question.