# Generic type in WCF - Runtime Error

Tags: c#, wcf

Interface:

```
[OperationContract]
[FaultContract(typeof(FaultLoggingErrorHandler))]
T MyService<T> (int importType);
```

Implementation:

```
public T UploadFile<T> (int importType)
{               
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(new object(), typeof(T));
}
```

For the above code I'm not getting any compile time error, but throwing runtime error.

> Error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException' occurred in MYServices.exe
>
> Additional information: Type 'T' cannot be exported as a schema type because it is an open generic type. You can only export a generic type if all its generic parameter types are actual types.

Edit: I'm expecting single service method to return generic object based on requirement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WCF exposing generic type 'T'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732411/wcf-exposing-generic-type-t)

Answer (score 0):

If your trying expose generic data type for client, I don't think you can do it straight away like this. Rather you can follow this

[WCF: Serialization and Generics](http://jeffbarnes.net/blog/post/2007/05/10/WCF-Serialization-and-Generics.aspx)